# maximum vector size reached prematurely

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am testing how large I can make a 1D vector on my computer. For this I am using the following MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> vec;

    const unsigned long long lim = 1E8;
    for(unsigned long long i=0; i<lim; i++)
    {
        vec.push_back(i);
    }
    cout << vec.max_size() << endl; //outputs 536.870.911 on my 32-bit system


    return 0;
}
```

As shown, `max_size()` gives me that a `std::vector` can contain 536.870.911 elements on my system. However, when I run the above MWE, I get the error

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc`

My computer has 2GB RAM, but 1E8 integers will only take up 381MB, so I don't see why I get a `bad_alloc` error?

Comment: That's what she said?

Comment: How much space 1e8 ints consumes is irrelevant for a vector of doubles...

Comment: What platform are you on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`1E8 = 100000000` and `sizeof(double) = 8` [in nearly all systems], so 762MB. Now, if we start with a vector of, say, 16 elements, and it doubles each time it "outgrows" the current size, to get space for 1E8 elements, we get the following sequence:

16, 32, 64, 128, 256, ...  67108864 (64M entries), the next one is 134217728, taking up 8 * 128M = 1GB, and you ALSO have to have space for a 64M * 8 = 512MB chunk at the same time, to copy the old data from. Given that there isn't a full 2GB of space available in a 32-bit process, because some memory is used up for stack, program code, DLL's, and other such things, finding a 1GB contiguous region of space may be hard when there is (more than) 512MB already occupied.

The problem of "I can't fit as much as I thought in my memory" is not an unusual problem.

One solution would be to use `std::vector::reserve()` to pre-allocate enough space. That is much more likely to work, since you only need a single large allocation, not two - and it won't require much more than the 762MB either, since it's allocated to the right size, not some arbitrary "double what it currently is".

Comment: But will it really double when it outgrows?

Comment: Yes, that is how the `vector` that I know works. Both Microsoft and GNU standard C++ libraries work that way, and I'm not aware of another one that doesn't work that way.

Comment: And, even if it doesn't, you need `old` + `new` size vectors, and if we put a different multiplier on the thing, it will have the same effect, except the `new` will be `x` times larger than `old` - where simply `x` isn't `2` - you still will run out of memory because there isn't space for the new and old at the same time, even though there is plenty of memory free before or after....